# How to ignore an import fail in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, import

I want to import a module in a script in React Native. This module has only `index.android.js` so import fails when on iOS.
How can i ignore it since i don't need that module in iOS?

I tried to use `if (Platform.OS == 'android') Module = require('module')` but it still throws an UnableToResolveError:

```
Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories: D:\myproject\node_modules
```

**Important**:
I don't want to modify the module.

Answer (score 0):

You could try utilize this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7271 It is not a full answer, but it could help you.